# Should merging to a blank tag allow bulk removal of that tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am attempting to obliterate a bad tag (`subjective`, in this case, although it was originally the `chunks` tag that ended up this way due to some experimentation; also note that I've since manually cleaned up the tags on each question).

When I go to the merge UI for the tag, and leave the merge *target* blank, I can still click "Preview Merge." This tells me that `subjective` will be removed from six questions, and added to none (which is exactly what I want). However, when I click "Perform Merge" I am greeted with the "Oops, something bad happened" error message screen. @Noctrine has reproduced the same behavior, so I don't think it's me.

The UX certainly implies that I can merge a tag with a blank tag to remove it from existence, and I think it's a useful feature as I've had to make a pass through bad tags two or three times now and manually get rid of them all.

Is this supposed to work the way I think? If not, it's certainly at least a bug that I'm allowed to preview a merge that will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that shouldn't happen, and will be fixed next time we deploy.

Comment: When you say "that shouldn't happen," do you mean the error, or the ability to remove a tag in this fashion? Because today I tried to merge away the 'indie' tag and was told I couldn't continue until I entered a merge target.